# How to make a google map to point by default to the USA?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

in the onload event I want to load a google map to show the USA.
What values do I need to put in the options {}?

```
   var myOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      ??????,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Position it to the latitude and longitude of the USA, and adjust the zoom.

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}; 
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

In most browsers after you search for a place on google maps, you can put

```
 javascript:void(prompt('',gApplication.getMap().getCenter()));
```

in the address bar to get the latitude and longitude coordinates

Or you can use reverse geocoding with a name like "USA" which would be something like this:

```
    geocoder.geocode( {'address': 'USA' }, function(results, status) {
      response($.map(results, function(item) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( item.geometry.location.lat(), item.geometry.location.lng()); 
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 3,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }; 
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
      }));
    });
```

Comment: I must use the lat/lang? I I think I read somewhere there are literal values for each region.

Comment: You can also use reverse geocoding or w/e it's called, i'll update the post above

Comment: yeah, because latitude and *longitude* are so hard to understand.

Comment: @Kerin - not sure if this was cynicism, so I'll answer seriously. If there is such a possibility in the API I would like to know it. Besides, if you read the documents (I am in the process of going through it) you'll notice that getting lang/lat is restricted to 2500 requests/day.